# Jackson - How to specify a single implementation for interface-referenced deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON-Object with Jackson. Because the target is an interface I need to specify which implementation should be used.

This information could be stored in the JSON-Object, using @JsonTypeInfo-Annotation. But I want to specify the implementation in source code because it's always the same.

Is this possible?

Comment: The question here is about a single implementation, but one could research about inheritance in general, and we should then see the @JsonTypeInfo annotation.  example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089484/deserialization-with-jsonsubtypes-for-no-value-missing-property-error/31016173#31016173

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a [SimpleAbstractTypeResolver](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleAbstractTypeResolver.html):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("CustomModel", Version.unknownVersion());

SimpleAbstractTypeResolver resolver = new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver();
resolver.addMapping(Interface.class, Implementation.class);

module.setAbstractTypes(resolver);

mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found an alternative if you want to specify the concrete implementation as an annotation http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Deserializing_Abstract_types

Comment: Sounds like a nice compromise!

Comment: @David Grant Where should we place SimpleAbstractTypeResolver in our code, i am using spring boot.

Comment: @har_shit take a look here for Spring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30725492/6400036

Answer (score 36):

There is another approach that will work if you have just single interface implementation.

```
public class ClassYouWantToDeserialize {
    @JsonDeserialize(as = ImplementationClass.class)
    private InterfaceClass property;
...
}
```

This question was answered a while ago but I want to give you another option that doesn't require to tune ObjectMapper and also much simpler then @JsonTypeInfo annotation.

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the OP question.

Comment: What if I have 2 Implementation and I want to deserialize based on some type field

Comment: @Gaurav this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506241/parse-to-a-subclass-by-default-with-jackson/27521288#27521288

Comment: Note that if target interface is nested into collection then  `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=NestedType.class)` should be used

Answer (score 10):

You can use  `@JsonDeserialize(as = ImplementationClass.class)` on the interface as well and all references will be deserialized the same way.

Note, if one of your Implementation classes is an enum, you might need `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` on the enum as well.