# Dynamically choosing which class to create object of from json

Tags: java, json, design-patterns

I have an interesting problem that I'm having trouble coming up with a clean solution for.  My application reads collections of json objects that it needs to deserialize to this or that class type based on a field in the json itself.  I have no control over the json structure or how it gets to my application.

I've created models for each type of object that could be coming to the application and I've reached a point where I'm trying to build a service that pulls out the 'type' field and then uses ObjectMapper to deserialize the json to the appropriate Model.

Json example:

```
{
    "message_type" : "model1"
    "other data" : "other value"
    ...
}
```

Models:

```
public class Model1 {
    ...
}

public class Model2 {
    ...
}
```

Service?:

```
public class DynamicMappingService {

    public ???? mapJsonToObject(String json) {
        String type = pullTypeFromJson();

        ???
    }

    private String pullTypeFromJson() {...}
}
```

I don't want a massive switch statement that says "If type value is this then deserialize to that" but I'm struggling to come up with something clean that does that.  I thought maybe a generic model class where the generic parameter is the Model Type and the only field is the instance of that model type but that doesn't seem right either and I'm not sure what that buys me.  I could also have some sort of empty abstract class that all of the models extend but that seems horrible too.  How do I deal with this?  Extra points for an example.

Comment: Changed the title to better reflect the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: As both `Model1` and `Model2` share no common supertype (they don't inherit from the same class other than `Object`) nor have a common interface there can be no way to get a proper return type for your `mapJsonToObject` function other than `Object`. What do you want to do with the returned object? As you don't know what it is you can't do common logic on some supertype

Comment: @roookeee I have to do some processing and re-serialize it to a slightly different model.

Comment: But you have to re-serialize both `Model1` and `Model2` to some other type right? As I explained - they have no common super type so this is only possibly with something like a visitor pattern in which every deserialized object visits the re-serializer. If you are interested I can add an example as an answer

Comment: You need to know what you are mapping into, otherwise you would have to use a `Map`. As far as I know, any other libraries/frameworks doing this sort of things make you to provide a proper type, otherwise the (de)serialization will fail.

Comment: @roookeee Yea, each model will have it's own 'output' model that it needs to be re-serialized to.  I'm interested in how the visitor patter would solve this, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the concept of a parent interface *Vehicle* with 2 classes *Car* and *Truck*.
In your case this means *Model1* and *Model2* should implement a common interface.

My test class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Tester {
    static ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setModel("sedan");
        String jsonCar=mapper.writeValueAsString(car);
        System.out.println(jsonCar);
        Vehicle c=mapper.readValue(jsonCar, Vehicle.class);
        System.out.println("Vehicle of type: "+c.getClass().getName());
        
        Truck truck=new Truck();
        truck.setPower(100);
        String jsonTruck=mapper.writeValueAsString(truck);
        System.out.println(jsonTruck);
        Vehicle t=mapper.readValue(jsonTruck, Vehicle.class);
        System.out.println("Vehicle of type: "+t.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Somewhere you will need to store a mapping between the value of the type field and the corresponding class. Depending on the location where you want this the implementation is different.

**1) The parent type holds the list of subtypes:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Car.class, name = "car"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Truck.class, name = "truck") }
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
          use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
          include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
          property = "type")
public interface Vehicle {
}
```

The models for *Car* and *Truck* are simple POJO without any annotations:

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {
    private String model;

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

**2) A separate resolver holds the mapping:**

*Vehicle* contains the extra annotation `@JsonTypeIdResolver`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonTypeIdResolver;

@JsonTypeInfo(
          use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
          include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
          property = "type")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(JsonResolver.class)
public interface Vehicle {
}
```

The *JsonResolver class* holds the mapping between the type field value and the class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeIdResolverBase;

public class JsonResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase {

    private static Map<String,Class<?>> ID_TO_TYPE=new HashMap<>();
    static {
        ID_TO_TYPE.put("car",Car.class);
        ID_TO_TYPE.put("truck",Truck.class);
    }
    public JsonResolver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Id getMechanism() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object value) {
        return value.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object value, Class<?> arg1) {
        return idFromValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) {
        return context.getTypeFactory().constructType(ID_TO_TYPE.get(id));
    }
}
```

**3) The json contains the full class name:**

If you accept your serialized json holds the full java class name, you don't need a resolver but specify `use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonTypeIdResolver;

@JsonTypeInfo(
          use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, 
          include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
          property = "type")
public interface Vehicle {
}
```

*Solution 3* is the easiest to implement but personally I don't like the idea to have full java class names in my data. It can be a potential risk if you start to refactor your java packages.

Comment: This is nice!  I wasn't aware of that Jackson feature.  Solution 1 seems like the best one to me, even if 'type' was the class name, which it isn't.  I'll just have to have a switch on `model.getClass().getName()` and cast the object to the specific implementation from there I guess.

Comment: What will this do when the 'type' in the json has no corresponding  `@JsonSubTypes.Type` ?

Comment: @b15 A simple test learns me it throws an exception: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'bike' into a subtype of [simple type, class be.test.json.Vehicle]: known type ids = [Vehicle, car, truck]
 at [Source: {"type":"bike","model":"electric"}; line: 1, column: 9]

Comment: @b15 also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506241/parse-to-a-subclass-by-default-with-jackson which can be a solution to define a default implementation. It depends on your business logic but maybe  it is better to just catch the exception and do the necessary in the catch block. You received data you don't understand so ...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the visitor pattern here:

```
class ScratchStackOverflowQuestion57102092 {
    interface Reserializer {
        void accept(Model1 model1);
        void accept(Model2 model2);
    }

    interface Reserializeable {
        void visit(Reserializer reserializer);
    }

    class Model1 implements Reserializeable {
        @Override
        public void visit(Reserializer reserializer) {
            reserializer.accept(this);
        }
    }

    class Model2 implements Reserializeable {
        @Override
        public void visit(Reserializer reserializer) {
            reserializer.accept(this);
        }
    }

    public class ReserializerImpl implements Reserializer {

        @Override
        public void accept(Model1 model1) {
            //TODO: reserialize and push the new object somewhere
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Model2 model2) {
            //TODO: reserialize and push the new object somewhere
        }
    }

    public class JsonConversion {
        //TODO: instantiate etc
        private Reserializer reserializer;

        public void handleJson(String json) {
            //TODO: use some framework like Jackson which can read type hints from JSON fields
            Reserializeable serialized = mapFromJson(json);
            serialized.visit(reserializer);
        }

    }
}
```

This is a simplified example on how to accomplish what you want but it lacks the following features for now:

- it doesn't return anything as you would have to have another visitor pattern and implement a receiver for each re-serialized (as you called it) object
- you still have to implement / find a library that reads type hints from the received json (like the code comment states, jackson can do this)

So you may have to adapt the given code a little :)

EDIT: Due to popular demand a fully fledged implementation which enables dynamic handling ob re-serialized objects via another visitor (it only lacks the Jackson usage that considers a type hint in the JSON). I apologize for the nearly dozen classes, there is just no shorter way. See function `exampleUsage()` on how this approach is used / how to define handlers for the different reconverted objects:

```
class ScratchStackOverflowQuestion57102092_V2 {
//////////////////////////////// INPUTS //////////////////////////////
    interface Reserializer {
        void accept(Model1 model1);
        void accept(Model2 model2);
    }

    interface Reserializeable {
        void visit(Reserializer reserializer);
    }


    class Model1 implements Reserializeable {
        @Override
        public void visit(Reserializer reserializer) {
            reserializer.accept(this);
        }
    }

    class Model2 implements Reserializeable {
        @Override
        public void visit(Reserializer reserializer) {
            reserializer.accept(this);
        }
    }

//////////////////////////////// RECONVERSION /////////////////////////

    interface ReconvertedVisitor {
        void accept(ReconvertedModel1 reconverted);
        void accept(ReconvertedModel2 reconverted);
    }

    interface ReconvertedModel {
        void visit(ReconvertedVisitor visitor);
    }

    //Some dummy object as an example
    class ReconvertedModel1 implements ReconvertedModel{

        @Override
        public void visit(ReconvertedVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.accept(this);
        }
    }

    //Some dummy object as an example
    class ReconvertedModel2 implements ReconvertedModel{
        @Override
        public void visit(ReconvertedVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.accept(this);
        }
    }

////////////////////////////// IMPLEMENTATIONS ///////////////////////////////
    public class ReserializerImpl implements Reserializer {

        private final ReconvertedVisitor visitor;

        public ReserializerImpl(ReconvertedVisitor visitor) {
            this.visitor = visitor;
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Model1 model1) {
            //TODO: do some real conversion
            ReconvertedModel1 reserializeResult = new ReconvertedModel1();
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(Model2 model2) {
            //TODO: do some real conversion
            ReconvertedModel2 reserializeResult = new ReconvertedModel2();
        }
    }

    public class JsonConversion {

        public void handleJson(String json, ReconvertedVisitor handler) {
            //TODO: use some framework like Jackson which can read type hints from JSON fields
            Reserializeable serialized = mapFromJson(json);
            ReserializerImpl reserializer = new ReserializerImpl(handler);
            serialized.visit(reserializer);
        }
    }

    public void exampleUsage() {
        //Just some sample, you could delegate to different objects in each accept
        class PrintingReconvertedVisitor implements ReconvertedVisitor {

            @Override
            public void accept(ReconvertedModel1 reconverted) {
                System.out.println(reconverted);
            }

            @Override
            public void accept(ReconvertedModel2 reconverted) {
                System.out.println(reconverted);
            }
        }
        JsonConversion conversion = new JsonConversion();
        conversion.handleJson("TODO: SOME REAL JSON HERE", new PrintingReconvertedVisitor());
    }
}
```

I am not too happy with the naming of the classes, maybe rename `Reserializer` so `ModelVisitor` or something appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by client code? I can't quite follow @daniu

Comment: How would you actually call the deserialization from json that is the OP's question?

Comment: You just call `JsonConversion.handleJson` and it would automatically call the "right" re-serializer in the `ReseriliazerImpl`. As I have explained in my answer: It has no return types for now and would also have to use the visitor pattern to handle different receivers / business logic. I can extend my answer to clarify if you like :)

Comment: Yes please. Are you going to create a model object for each type and call `visit` for all of them?

Comment: @daniu here you go. As the OP explained every input model has a distinct re-converted object ( I stuck to his terminology in my post)

Comment: Hm..  Looking at this I have to wonder if a switch statement is the lesser of two evils here.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different problems here: creating an object of unknown type and doing something meaningful with it afterwards. If your created type really depends on the value of a node within the json, you'll not get around to creating a mapping from that String to the class it will create. A huge if-then-else block will not be useful beyond two or three classes.

**Creation**

You could create a registry singleton that you use to maintain this mapping.

```
public enum ClassByNodeMapping {
    INSTANCE;
    final Map<String, Class<?>> mapping = new HashMap<>();

    public void addMapping(String nodeValue, Class<?> clazz) {
        mapping.put(nodeValue, clazz);
    }
    public Class<?> getMapping(String nodeValue) {
        return mapping.get(nodeValue);
    }
}
```

You can fill this per class:

```
@Data
class Model1 {
    static {
        ClassByNodeMapping.INSTANCE.addMapping("model1", Model1.class);
    }
    private String model1Value;
}
```

But even then, you'll need to instantiate `Model1` once before it will be registered (to guarantee the class has been loaded. So your client code would look like this:

```
class Scratch {
    static {
        // need to instantiate the models once to trigger registration
        Model1 model = new Model1();
        Model2 model2 = new Model2();
    }
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json1 = "{\"type\": \"model1\", \"model1Value\": \"m1\"}";
        String json2 = "{\"type\": \"model2\", \"model2Value\": \"m2\"}";

        System.out.println(deserialize(json1));
        System.out.println(deserialize(json2));
    }

    private static Object deserialize(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
        Class<?> type = ClassByNodeMapping.INSTANCE.getMapping(jsonNode.get("type").textValue());
        return mapper.readValue(json, type);
    }
}
```

**Processing**

Now you have created objects, but since they're of type `Object`, there's not much you can do with them. In the comments to your question, you said something like "reserialize", I'm not sure what that means; the general concept is consumption here - the object is created and then something is done with it. You can use the visitor concept from the other answer here, but I find it somewhat confusing.

You can extend the mapping by also including a handler. Generally, you'd want to separate the two, but in this case it might be needed to retain type safety.

```
enum ClassByNodeMapping {
    INSTANCE;
    final Map<String, Class<?>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> handlerMapping = new HashMap<>();

    public <T>void addMapping(String nodeValue, Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> handler) {
        mapping.put(nodeValue, clazz);
        handlerMapping.put(clazz, handler);
    }
    public Class<?> getMapping(String nodeValue) {
        return mapping.get(nodeValue);
    }
    public Consumer<Object> getHandler(Class<?> clazz) {
        return (Consumer<Object>) handlerMapping.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

Which makes your registration code something like this

```
@Data
class Model1 {
    static {
        // you'd probably not want to do the registration here,
        // assuming your handler code is outside
        ClassByNodeMapping.INSTANCE.addMapping("model1", Model1.class, Model1::handle);
    }
    private String model1Value;

    private static void handle(Model1 m1) {
        System.out.printf("handling as model1: %s%n", m1);
    }
}
```

And your (test) client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json1 = "{\"type\": \"model1\", \"model1Value\": \"m1\"}";
    String json2 = "{\"type\": \"model2\", \"model2Value\": \"m2\"}";

    handle(json1);
    handle(json2);
}

private static void handle(String json) throws IOException {
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
    Class<?> type = ClassByNodeMapping.INSTANCE.getMapping(jsonNode.get("type").textValue());
    Consumer<Object> handler = ClassByNodeMapping.INSTANCE.getHandler(type);
    Object o = mapper.readValue(json, type);
    handler.accept(o);
}
```

**Caveat**

I'd consider the whole concept a code smell. I'd definitely strive for incoming channel containing data of only one type - whether it be separate REST endpoints, Kafka topics or whatever.

Comment: Yea, we're working with a third party that sends us batches of these events of different types in a single message so there's nothing I can do.

Comment: @b15 you can create a distributor that only analyzes the type field and forward the contrasting json part to the appropriate endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or / and [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for this.