# Deserialization with @JsonSubTypes for no value - missing property error

Tags: java, json, jackson

I deserialize jsons like this:

```
{
  "type":"a",
  "payload" : {...}
}
```

where payload type depends on type. My class:

```
public class Sth<T extends Payload> {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;
    @Valid
    private T payload;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        property = "type",
        visible = true,
        defaultImpl = NoClass.class)
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = APayload.class, name = "a"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BPayload.class, name = "b"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CPayload.class, name = "c")})
    public void setPayload(T payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    }

}
```

I have also type "d" with no payload. If I try to deserialize:

```
{
  "type":"d",
  "payload" : null
}
```

it works but it doesn't work with no payload:

```
{
  "type":"d",
}
```

How to make it work with last example?

Stacktrace of error that I get:

```
[error] Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Missing property 'payload' for external type id 'type
[error]  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:700)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.ExternalTypeHandler.complete(ExternalTypeHandler.java:160)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithExternalTypeId(BeanDeserializer.java:690)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithExternalTypeId(BeanDeserializer.java:639)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:266)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2965)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1587)
[error]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:1931)
[error]     at play.libs.Json.fromJson(Json.java:47)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also encountered this issue, and could not find an elegant solution using the mechanisms provided by Jackson (custom `BeanDeserializer`, `BeanDeserializerModifier`, etc.).

It looks like a bug in the way external type IDs are handled. I worked around it by:

1. deserializing the JSON tring to a `JsonNode`;
2. manually inserting a `null` node if the required property is not present;
3. mapping the `JsonNode` to my desired value type.

My code looks something like the following:

```
public <T> T decode(String json, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);

    if (jsonNode.isObject() && (jsonNode.get("payload") == null  || jsonNode.get("payload").size() == 0)) {
        ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
        objectNode.putNull("payload");
    }

    return mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, type);
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I did. I asked the same question on Jackson forum and AFAIK there is no better solution than this. You missed one case. Jackson cannot deserialize object properly when payload not set OR is set as {} so I edited your answer and accepted it.

Comment: @jasiustasiu Did your edit get rejected? What do you want to change?

Comment: I don't know why my edit was rejected. I edited your answer again and it seems to work now

Comment: Yeah, I approved it myself. When you did your edit the first time, I wasn't around, so it got rejected by other reviewers, probably because they thought it was too big of a change.

Answer (score 14):

There is explicit deserialization feature for this:

```
new ObjectMapper().configure(
DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_EXTERNAL_TYPE_ID_PROPERTY, 
false);
```

Comment: Changing configuration is good solution but it's better to add to application properties:
    `spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_MISSING_EXTERNAL_TYPE_ID_PROPERTY`

Comment: That is spring boot specific.  If you're not using spring boot you'll still need to configure the object mapper.

Comment: This is the correct answer, @jasiustasiu – it would be great if you marked it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have encountered the same issue you documented.

I was receiving the following exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Missing property 'content' 
  for external type id 'contentType
```

I ended up getting it working by adding the [@JsonTypeId](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeId.html) annotation to the type field.

```
public interface Content {
}

public class Post implements Content {
  public String content = "bar";
}

public class Foo {

  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
                property = "contentType")
  @JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Post.class, name = "post")
  })
  public Content content;

  @JsonTypeId
  public ContentType contentType;

  public enum ContentType {
    "post"
  }
}
```