# Deserialize optional polymorphic fields with jackson

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

### Problem

For example, I have a list of some products in my cart like cinema ticket, carsharing and new book.

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Cinema Ticket"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Car Sharing",
    "properties": { ... }
  },
  {
    "name": "New Book",
  }
]
```

As you can see, not all products have `properties`.
**Note:** this field is polymorphic.

### Question

Can I turn "non-existing" field `properties` into `null` using Jackson or it's better to change api?
And if I can then how to do that?

**Jackson Version: 2.10.1**

Thanks for answers!

Comment: You could ignore it during serialisation by adding [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) to the corresponding field in your DTO.

Comment: Am I right, if I will ignore it, it will be always null? @TA

Comment: yes, wasn't this your intention?

Comment: Sorry, probably I didn't explain completely. For some products I need this field. The problem is only  that for some products there are not properties. @TA

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have something like:

```
public class BaseProduct {
   public String name;
}

public class CarSharing extends BaseProduct {
    public String properties;
}

public class Book extends BaseProduct {
}
```

Instead of having the **properties** field set to null when is not there, you can use Jackson polymorphic functionality to not show it. Something like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
public class BaseProduct {
     public String name;
}
```

The output would be:

```
[
  {
    "type": ".Book",
    "name": "Book name"
  },
  {
    "type": ".CarSharing",
    "name": "Car share name",
    "properties": "a property field"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I would use this solution (polymorphic classes instead props), but api does not implement this way :(

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot change the JSON produced, or that you cannot change the classes? Are you in control of just the client?

Comment: I suppose there is a misunderstanding. I need to deserialize json already produced by api in that way. In other words, I want to "fill in" missing field if it isn't in json. @Franjavi

Comment: That is the default behavior in Jackson. If the field is not present it will be set to null in the POJO, so you don't need to change anything for it.

Comment: However, it's crashing 
Probably I've found a solution. ObjectMapper has to be configured.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933297/11475298