# How do I obtain the Jackson ObjectMapper in use by Spring 4.1?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Spring 4.1 instantiates a Jackson `ObjectMapper` instance. I have reason to want to `@Autowire` that instance into one of my controllers: The controller does some minor JSON parsing of its own using Jackson, but the `ObjectMapper` it uses should be the one and same instance that Spring itself is using. How do I go about accomplishing that?

Note that I'm not asking how to custom configure the `ObjectMapper` in use by Spring; I'm happy with the defaults. I just want to fish the instance used by Spring out so that I can re-use the existing instance in my own code.

Comment: Are you sure it creates a bean that can be Autowired and not local instances of ObjectMapper? If yes, can't this be fetched from the 'load bean from Context of type ObjectMapper.class'?

Comment: Adding an `@Autowire` property of type `ObjectMapper` in the controller is not enough. Apparently, Spring does not expose it as a standard bean.

Comment: In test environment I get it by adding `@Autowired` on `ObjectMapper` and `@JsonTest` on test class

Answer (score 67):

If you're using Spring Boot with Jackson on your classpath and default implementation for JSON parsing in your REST controller, then this should work:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Tested with Spring-boot 1.4.0.M2 which uses spring 4.3.0.RC1 and throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Comment: First: works with spring boot 1.5.3 when autowiring in a component. Second: WARNING: This is one of the most dangerous ideas i've had so far. Because of its singleton-nature, you could get in very ugly problems using the Spring Objectmapper as an @Autowired bean, e.g. no Object in your Controllers is serialized anymore, because you changed a serializationfeature (unwrap_root_value, anyone?) in ANY class using the autowired mapper. So please: JUST use it when you are sure you just need the ootb-features of the mapper. For EVERY other usecase, extend it and create your own custom mapper

Comment: @Dominik is it safe if I only use the Springs autowired Object Mapper to 'writeValueAsString'? I am working on transaction logging and want to capture the output exactly how it is returned to the user.

Comment: @afaulconbridge A common problem that I have had many times is importing by mistake org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper instead of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper which is the package Spring Boot actually create a bean from. Changing this, autowired used to work for me.

Comment: Is it thread safe?

Answer (score 30):

As was said by others, you can't `@Autowired` it in directly into your controller.

@Emerson Farrugia's suggestion to create a new instance using

```
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build()
```

also didn't work for me because the obtained instance was not following the `spring.jackson.*` configuration properties, which I needed it to.

---

The solution I found was to obtain the ObjectMapper from Spring's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which is injectable.

So I autowired it:

```
@Autowired
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter springMvcJacksonConverter;
```

and then get the ObjectMapper from it like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = springMvcJacksonConverter.getObjectMapper();
```

This instance behaves exactly as Spring MVC's own message conversion - it probably *is* the same instance anyway.

Comment: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is not injectable :(

Comment: Injectable but the objectmapper is null, so NPE.

Comment: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter doesn't seem to be injectable in plain, non-Boot Spring either.

Answer (score 24):

If you take a look at `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, you'll see that it creates a new `ObjectMapper`, but doesn't expose it as a bean. There's a getter, but the only way I've fished it out in the past is when I created the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` myself, e.g.

```
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = jacksonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);

        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter);
    }
}
```

If you're working with Spring Boot, there's a [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) in the manual dedicated to working with the `ObjectMapper` If you create a default `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` `@Bean`, you should be able to autowire that same `ObjectMapper` instance in your controller.

Comment: Right, I've encountered this path but it involves re-creating the default Jackson settings that Spring creates. Which I don't want to have to do.

Comment: FWIW, Spring creates more than one `ObjectMapper`. The JSON message converter creates one, as does the XML converter. Creating a third that's identical to the JSON message converter is as simple as `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build()`. But if you really need it to be the same instance, call that line in a `@Bean` and wire it in wherever you need it. Spring will take care of wiring it into the converters.

Comment: Why the heck spring uses different instances of OM. This is so confusing. Spring Boot documentation says that spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true is just the only thing that you need to have web response prettified. But it really just changes the bean, and has no effect on the message converted.

Comment: You need to add @Configuration on the class declaration for this to work

Comment: The doc says, "If you want to replace the default `ObjectMapper` completely, either define a `@Bean` of that type and mark it as `@Primary` or, if you prefer the builder-based approach, define a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` `@Bean`. Note that, in either case, doing so disables all auto-configuration of the `ObjectMapper`." So, creating the `@Bean` means overwriting all settings in yml/properties files. What if I want to get the configured objectmapper? The Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder with @Autowired always return null.

Comment: Since Spring 3.1 the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, so just use the WebMvcConfigurer interface directly

Comment: @togise it's been deprecated since 5.0, not 3.1.

Answer (score 16):

The `ObjectMapper` is created by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, and you can inject the builder using:

```
@Autowired
private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder;
```

Then use `mapperBuilder.build()` to build an `ObjectMapper` instance, and this instance can use configurations in `application.properties`. [Official doc here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: Trying to work out how I'd then take that new builder and "install" it into Spring MVC default message conversion... (and I'm plain Spring MVC, not Spring Boot).

Comment: Alternatively, the builder can configure an existing mapper with `mapperBuilder.configure(mapper)`. This is very useful in Kotlin, where you probably want to get the mapper instance from jackson-module-kotlin's jacksonObjectMapper(), for better Kotlin support.

Answer (score 10):

I have debugged into source code of Spring Boot and found that only when we launch the whole context `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` will contain the config we put in `application.yml`.

This means, if we want to generate an ObjectMapper in a Spring Boot test, with JUnit 5, we have to:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class SomeTest {
    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder;
    ...

    @Test
    void testObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = builder.build();


    }
```

We cannot only make `@SpringBootTest(classes = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.class)` to generate this builder.

When we `bootRun` we don't have this problem.

The configuration is set in `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration#customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder)` method.

[image]

Comment: I think @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) is implicitly included by @SpringBootTest

Comment: You can use the '@JsonTest' test slice to get the configured mapper without launching the entire app like '@SpringBootTest' does. Much faster. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-test-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

When you try to @Autowire the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter it gives you: 
`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' available: expected single matching bean but found 4: mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,jacksonHttpMessageConverter,halJacksonHttpMessageConverter,alpsJsonHttpMessageConverter`.

This is not a big issue, you can just change your variable name to one of the above to  get that instance:
`@Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halJacksonHttpMessageConverter;`

Answer (score 1):

An Update for Spring 4.3:

- As of Spring 4.3, classes with a single constructor can omit the @Autowired annotation
- Consequently, if you add a constructor which takes an ObjectMapper parameter it will be autowired with the Jackson ObjectMapper instance without needing to use the annotation @Autowired

Answer (score -3):

### A two-stepper if you will;

1. At your `@SpringBootApplication` class, add:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ObjectMapper mapper() {
     return new ObjectMapper();
   }
   ```
2. Anywhere you wish to use `ObjectMapper`:

   ```
   @Autowired
   ObjectMapper mapper;
   ```

Peace!

Comment: This would provide an ObjectMapper instance, but not the same one used by Spring. Any custom Jackson configurations added in your application config will not exist here unless you set your configurations up in 2 places.