# How to obtain Jackson Object Mapper in Spring Rest mvc 5?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I want to obtain the `ObjectMapper` (or mappers) that Spring 5 creates, configures and uses to serialize and deserialize data exchanges on my Rest resources (i.e. to call [readerForUpdating()](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating-java.lang.Object-) on it or to provide further configuration such as adding mixins).

I've tried the solutions proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30060006/3127111) but none worked: I'm not using Spring Boot and neither of `ObjectMapper` or `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` can be `@Autowired`.

In particular, I've tried reconfiguring the ObjectMapper from the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages=...)
public class WebappConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        // ...
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> c : converters) {

            if(c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper o = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c).getObjectMapper();

                //o.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
                o.addMixIn(WorkStamp.class, WorkStampApi.class);
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

But that's not working either, as that mixin removes a field from the serialized object but the produced JSON still has that field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's my solution: basically, during webapp initialization I obtain a reference to the mapper inside the relevant Spring message converter, I then store that reference to be retrieved later as a bean from the context.

This is the Spring webapp configuration class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages= { "..." })
@PropertySource("...")
public class WebappConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private ObjectMapper jacksonMapper;

    @Bean(name="jacksonMapper",autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        return jacksonMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> it = converters.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            HttpMessageConverter<?> conv = it.next();

            if(conv instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) conv;
                jacksonMapper = jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here's an example of that Object Mapper usage:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="...")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @PostMapping(path= { "..." })
    public ApiResponse<?> post() {

        try {
            // ...

            ObjectMapper om = (ObjectMapper) ctx.getBean("jacksonMapper");

            // ...

            return new ApiResponse<>();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: (ObjectMapper) ctx.getBean("jacksonMapper")   <--- this is what you should never ever do. What's wrong with using "@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper" instead?

Comment: @AgostonHorvath (I'm new to Spring) autowiring used to stay null when I wrote this piece of code, so I opted for that - I did a quick try right now but it seems it's being succesfully autowired.

Comment: @AgostonHorvath I found a place where `@Autowiring` doesn't work: with the given `WebappConfig` class code, that bean cannot be injected in a `SmartLifecycle` implementation instance member (although it is only being used in its `start()` method), do you have any suggestion?