# Jackson Objectmapper is not initialized by Spring after configured as bean when I try to de serialize abstarct class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using Jackson xml version 2.9.9 in spring boot application.

I have a controller that accepts Vehicle which is an abstract class that has 2 child classes.
When I pass JSON data from postman I am not able deserialize Vehicle since object mapper which is auto wired is always null(I configured objectmapper as a bean since I am setting deserialiers as simple modules to mapper). Please look at the example code in https://github.com/vin0010/Jackson-Mapper-Issue

> Controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/jackson", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void forSingleObject(@RequestBody MyModel myModel){
        System.out.println("Deserialization successful");
    }
```

> MyModel.java

```
public class MyModel {
    private String name;
    private Vehicle value;
}
```

> Vehicle.java

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private String vehicleName;
}
```

> Car.java

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{
    private String carType;
    private String carDriverName;
}
```

> Auto.java

```
public class Auto extends Vehicle {
    private String autoType;
    private String autoDriverName;
}
```

> ObjectMapper bean configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build();
        List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Vehicle.class, new VehicleDeserializer()));
        objectMapper.registerModules(modules);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

> VehicleDeserializer.java

```
public class VehicleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Vehicle> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Override
    public Vehicle deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        Vehicle vehicle=null;
        if (!jsonNode.findPath("carDriverName").equals("")){
            vehicle = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, Car.class);
        }else if (!jsonNode.findPath("autoDriverName").equals("")){
            vehicle = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, Auto.class);
        }
        return vehicle;
    }
}
```

> JSON input

```
{
    "name": "Bajaj",
    "value": {
        "autoDriverName": "Mr Auto Driver",
        "autoType": "commercial"
    }
}
```

> Problem : 
>    Object mapper is not injected and its null.

I just found out that neither object mapper is initialized in VehicleDeserializer.java nor I found a way to deserialize string to Car/Auto without the help of ObjectMapper.

I tried every method in [How do I obtain the Jackson ObjectMapper in use by Spring 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060006/how-do-i-obtain-the-jackson-objectmapper-in-use-by-spring-4-1) but nothing seems to work.

I added this as a separate question because either I need a fix the injection Objectmapper or deserialize Car/Auto without using Objectmapper(still I can only have Fasterxml).

Creating a new ObjectMapper inside VehicleDeserializer.java is not helping since it always return null object for Car/Auto even if I add deserializers to it. 
I made this example since its just a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
I need jackson to complete the de serialization

Comment: I'm afraid it's going to be very difficult to help you on this one without a minimum reproducible example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Use as few fields / small code as possible, but make sure that what you have posted compiles and runs without anything else. You may even find the cause of the problem yourself while doing that.

Comment: Since you say that it can deserialize `List<Metric>` but breaks after, try reproducing this with just array of metrics and some other field. Trim both the class and the JSON, that should help. Also, are you quite sure you have all the json text and it doesn't cut at the random point?

Comment: There are so many things to add here, Models are huge. Let me try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I made some findings but yet to fix the complete problem. I think new question is not a good option, let me make edits in the question to update current issue.

Comment: I think that your MapperConfig class is in wrong package. Seems like ComponentScan is not scanning it. Try to move your ObjectMapper bean in class where your @SpringBootApplication is and if that works, you can be sure that  MapperConfig should be in folder where ComponentScan can scan it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to attempt to inject `ObjectMapper` in your custom deserializer. You could use:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
```

If you don't need any method from `ObjectMapper`, casting is not necessary:

```java
ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();
```

Comment: OMG, Finally, this is what I was missing, it solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @vinoth10 Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer then. It's the best way to say _thank you_ :)

Comment: I am just wondering why
objectMapper.readValue(node.toString(), Car.class) - this works
But
objectMapper1.readValue(jasonParser, Car.class) - it doesn't.
Apart from this I got answer for my issue. Thank you.

Comment: @vinoth10 There's no such `objectMapper1.readValue(jasonParser, Car.class)` in your code. I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: I mean after you answer I just did 
ObjectMapper objectmapper1= (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @vinoth10 `@Autowired` only works for Spring beans. That deserializer is not a Spring bean and you instantiating it manually. Spring doesn't manage it, so `@Autowired` won't work. In the approach described in by answer, you obtain the `ObjectCodec` (which actually is an instance of `ObjectMapper`) used by the `JsonParser`. There's no magic there.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for your issue, you are doing this:

```
modules.add(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Vehicle.class, new VehicleDeserializer()));
```

you are instantiating the object yourself so the mapper will be null.

Comment: Sorry @stacker, I dont understand. I think its fine to add a deserializer manually. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: by adding it manually you have to manage the object yourself, spring won't be responsible for autowiring ObjectMapper, so its value will be null,

Answer (score 1):

You made some mistakes in your deserialiser:

- Because you registered your deserialiser to `ObjectMapper` object inside deserialiser you can get it by `(ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec()` where `parser` is `JsonParser` type.
- `findPath` method returns `JsonNode` not `String` so `.equals("")` always return `false`. You should use `isMissingNode` method instead.
- When you use `readTree` method on `parser` object you can not use it again because deserialisation was already done and you have a `JsonNode`. Since now, you should use it. You can use `convertValue` method to convert it to desired `Class`.

This is how it should be:

```
class VehicleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Vehicle> {

    @Override
    public Vehicle deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        // cast to ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();

        // read JSON as tree to JsonNode object
        // since now `parser` should not be used anymore.
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(parser);
        Vehicle vehicle = null;
        if (!root.findPath("carDriverName").isMissingNode()) {
            vehicle = mapper.convertValue(root, Car.class);
        } else if (!root.findPath("autoDriverName").isMissingNode()) {
            vehicle = mapper.convertValue(root, Auto.class);
        }
        return vehicle;
    }
}
```