# Spring boot: LocalTime serialization with ISO format

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

In a very simple Spring-boot reactive project, with no specific configuration (but the one attempted below), I need to serialize `LocalTime` (and related classes like `LocalDate` too) in an ISO form. By default each property is serialized individually, which makes sense from an Object point of view. But I need single string property in ISO format.

Several mentions of that issue have been made, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956175/json-java-8-localdatetime-format-in-spring-boot), [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/consume-produce-json/) or in lesser extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060006/how-do-i-obtain-the-jackson-objectmapper-in-use-by-spring-4-1).

None work. I wonder what I do wrong or if these links are just outdated and the mechanism in spring updated/changed since.

The central test I've made is by having a `bean` register the appropriate module:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper customJson() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .build();

        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

My way of identifying that the serialization is not in the ISO format is by looking at my swagger-ui description of my object showing my `endTime` property as follows (when the actual result I'm trying to achieve is `"endTime": "some ISO string"`):

```
"endTime": {
  "hour": 0,
  "minute": 0,
  "nano": 0,
  "second": 0
},
```

So the question is: How do I configure single string formatting for `LocalDate` in Spring Boot (Reactive)?

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38731094/10871900)?

Comment: @dan1st I tried this and went away from it since `jackson-datatype-jsr310` is a deprecated module. And having no luck with `JavaTimeModule` triggered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Entity()));
}

static class Entity {
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    public ZonedDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

This is a modified quote from this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your objective by disabling the WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS feature in jackson

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) 
                .modules(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();
```

This will make is serialize it in ISO format