# How to get the SpringBoot (Jackson)-objectMapper in a debugger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea, jackson

I would like some way to look at a json-string generated from an object I have in the debugger while on a breakpoint.

There are alternatives that work but are not quite what I want: I know I can annotate the constructor of a service and have Spring dependency-inject it for me, as for example explained here: [How do I obtain the Jackson ObjectMapper in use by Spring 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060006/how-do-i-obtain-the-jackson-objectmapper-in-use-by-spring-4-1), I am also aware I can create a *new* object Mapper from static methods in the Jackson-library, but I want to use the objectMapper as it is configured in the real application.

I am using intellij as a frontend for the java-debugger, SpringBoot 3.1.2 and jackson-core 2.15.2, though I suppose those things should not be too relevant.