# Jackson, how define a default type impl for interface field?

Tags: java, jackson

I need to deserialize a JSON to a Java class with a `Serializable` field. 
In the following Java class the `value` field is an interface, the idea is that the view can send values of types: `String`, `Double`, `Long` and `ArrayList`. If I change the type of value field from `Serializable` to `Object`, it works as expected.

```java
public class UpdateAttribute implements Serializable {
    //..
    // There is something like: @JsonImplType(Object.class)
    private Serializable value;
}
```

My question is, there is such a way to define a default class type to the value field? Something like: `@JsonImplType(Object.class)`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is use an annotation from `jackson-databind` module.
A similiar question was asked here: [Jackson - How to specify a single implementation for interface-referenced deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688503/jackson-how-to-specify-a-single-implementation-for-interface-referenced-deseri).

```java
public class UpdateAttribute implements Serializable {
    //..
    @JsonDeserialize(as = Object.class)
    private Serializable value;
}
```

However, there is a detail to be considered. The `setValue` method of `UpdateAttribute` can't be declared with a `Serializable` argument. Because Jackson don't know about the casting from `Object` to `Serializable`. Therefore, the final class should look like:

```java
public class UpdateAttribute implements Serializable {

    @JsonDeserialize(as = Object.class)
    private Serializable value;

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = (Serializable) value;
    }
}
```